# Kubernetes, pods with unique database server vs one shared database server

Tags: docker, database, kubernetes

I'm developing an application that is shipped as a cloud service, that is there are `n` instances of that application and each is completely separated from one another and each of those separated clones store the data in its own pgsql `database`.

Currently there is one single database server and I manually set up the docker images of this application and connect that image to newly created database on the common database server. This process is getting very time and effort consuming so I would like to automate that with *Kubernetes*.

I've designed a structure with one main server that will orchestrate and automate the creation of nodes, but one of many questions that arose is what is the best way to deal with data storage of such architecture?

Is it better to host one database server per *pod*, or should I set up one *storage* unit for the whole *node* and make *pods* connect to it? Is the thing that I would like to achieve even suitable for Kubernetes? That is to automate a deployment of a single *docker* image that will be replicated as a completely separate instances, each with it's own database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have so many single application instances, setting up separate database instance for it composed in every `Pod` could be quite tedious task. Of course those `Pods` shouldn't be just bare `Pods` but they should be managed by some controller such as `Deployment` or `Statefulset` (which is more suitable for stateful applications such as databases). No matter if the number of replicas it creates and manages is only one, you should use the controller as it will handle `Pod` life-cycle for you.

Placing both **application** and **database** in a single `Pod` isn't recommended approach. According to **microservices architecture** approach, all the elements of your application such as its **front-end** part, **back-end api** and **database** shouldn't be tightly coupled i.e. placing all of those elements in a single `Pod` is definitely not recommended approach. It's still possible and technically feasible but has a lot of disadvantages.

It's much better to deploy each instance of your application as a separate `Deployment` if they should be totally independent from one another rather than run as a set of `Pods` being managed by one `Deployment`. Each of those `Pods` may connect to database instance, managed by separate [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

When you already have your database server set up, it can be also used by your `Pods`. It's still acceptable approach as containers are generally not the best choice for running **stateful apps** and in many cases it might be even better to run them on bare metal or virtual machines.

If your database server has its fully quallified domain name (FQDN), you can simply define [`ExternalName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) `Service` type pointing to this domain name:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

> When looking up the host `my-service.prod.svc.cluster.local`, the
>   cluster DNS Service returns a `CNAME` record with the value
>   `my.database.example.com`. Accessing `my-service` works in the same
>   way as other Services but with the crucial difference that redirection
>   happens at the DNS level rather than via proxying or forwarding.
>   Should you later decide to move your database into your cluster, you
>   can start its Pods, add appropriate selectors or endpoints, and change
>   the Service’s `type`.

Then you can use your `Service` name (when working a in a single namespace) in your app to connect to your database behind it. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/#creating-the-frontend) you can see how **front-end** part of the application can be connected with its **back-end**. If your application supports config file where you can specify database url, you can pass it to your `Pod` via [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/), without a need of changing your code and rebuild your docker image.

I hope it helps and clarifies a bit the available options.